# Adding HttpConfigurationExtensions to ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

One of the projects I'm working on has the extension class `HttpConfigurationExtensions` from `System.Web.Http 5.2.2`

To add it to another project, I installed the nuget

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.2.2
```

However, it doesn't seem to have added `HttpConfigurationExtensions` though the assemblies are identical.

**I guess I'm doing something wrong here. What could it be and how would you go about adding `HttpConfigurationExtensions` to your project?**

### PS:

This is what the disassembler shows for `System.Web.Http.cs` for both projects

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

// Assembly System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// MVID: 214E5BA0-B5E8-43DD-B986-3648DF7435EE
// References: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// References: System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// References: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// References: System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// References: System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// References: System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// References: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
// References: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// References: System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft Corporation.")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("Serviceable", "True")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Microsoft ASP.NET MVC")]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Extension]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.5")]
[assembly: SatelliteContractVersion("5.2.2.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("5.2.20826.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("5.2.2-20826 (66298100f4e349d3812b1aad32c5278c256a2cdd)")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("System.Web.Http")]
[assembly: Guid("70cecdcd-46f5-492b-9e1f-1d9a947f1fd1")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("System.Web.Http.Test, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("System.Web.Http.Integration.Test, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.2.2.0")]
```

However, when I browse the assembly through the Assembly Explorer (from Resharper) it doesn't show any classes in `System.Web.Http` in the project which I added the nuget (which has `HttpConfigurationExtensions` missing).

[image]

But the other project has all the relevant classes
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with a project I was attempting to manually at Web API to.

Try reinstalling it via Nuget:

`update-package microsoft.aspnet.webapi -reinstall`